# Initializing List<T> with given number of nulls without loop?

Tags: java, list, initialization

Can a `List<T>` be initialized to contain a given number of `null`s, where T is a type parameter of the class of which the list is a member? I sure can do it with a loop, but like to know whether it is possible without.

```
List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>(numEls);
```

creates a list of the given capacity, but size 0, so `myList.get(x)` fails for all `x`, and so does, e.g. `myList.set(numEls-1,null)`.

```
myList = Arrays.asList(new T[numEls]);
```

does not compile, and

```
 myList = (List<T>) Arrays.asList(new Object[numEls]);
```

compiles in Eclipse (with an Unchecked cast warning), but not with javac.

---

**Update:** Thank you for the answers! However, I found another, quite short, solution close to my last attempt above, which compiles both in eclipse and with our automated build system: *Cast the array, not the list!*

```
myList = Arrays.asList((T[]) new Object[numEls]);
```

Comment: Why do you need to solve this without a loop? It's pretty unreasonable. Just call `ensureCapacity` and then *n* times `add(null)`.

Comment: @RolandIllig I do not _need_ to solve it without a loop, I would just like to know whether it is possible.

Comment: Why are you going to such lengths to avoid a one line loop, by replacing it with something much more complicated? If you know the size you want to can wrap an `Object[]`.

Comment: Not a solution either: but you _can_ write an implementation of `List` that behaves as a sparse list and returns `null` for all `get(i) | i < size()`. IMHO, "initializing a `List`" doesn't make sense since `List` is just an interface.

Comment: @AlistairIsrael Fair point. What I meant was "initialize something implementing list", which may be the ordinary `ArrayList`, or the list type `Arrays.asList(...)` returns, or another, whichever works best.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The loop is not really such a big problem. But since an array of a given size `n` by default contains `n` `null` values, and since the `Arrays` class can wrap an array in a `List`, I thought it might not be that difficult.

Comment: @ame.b It is simple, but rarely required IMHO.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't need to mutate the list...

```
List<T> result = Collections.nCopies(num, (T) null);
```

... or alternately

```
List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(Collections.nCopies(num, (T) null));
```

Comment: Please explain second option. Using this when I try to access list it gives me NullPointerException. My code                              List<ProfileSectionDTO> psDTOs = new ArrayList<ProfileSectionDTO>(Collections.nCopies(15, (ProfileSectionDTO) null));

Comment: How are you trying to access the list?  It's full of nulls.

Comment: Yeah. Stupid me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You would need to use reflection to instantiate a backing array `T[]` using [`Array.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-):

```
public static <T> List<T> getListWithNulls(Class<T> componentType, int length) {
   T[] array = (T[])Array.newInstance(componentType, length);
   return new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```

As you can see, this requires a reference to the `Class<T>` object representing the type of `T`:

```
List<String> strListWithNulls = getListWithNulls(String.class, 100);
```

Also make sure not to confuse the classes `java.lang.reflect.Array` and `java.util.Arrays` which are both used here.

Finally, note that reflection is going to be much slower than just using a loop.

Comment: Why do you need the new ArrayList<T>? Arrays.asList already returns a List instance.

Comment: @dmeister - [That method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) returns a `List` backed by the array. In order to have a resizeable list, it needs to be copied to another `List` implementation.

Comment: @KublaiKhan Thank you! In fact, dmeister's suggestion would fit the purpose as the List size is fixed in my case (but I did not say that in the question). Anyway, I was hoping for a solution whose code would be shorter than the loop, but if I cannot have that, I will not blame the messenger. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Not really a solution, but you wanted to avoid a loop.

```
void fillNullList(List<T> list, count) {
   if (count > 0) {
       list.add(null);
       fillNullList(list, count - 1);
   }
}
```

Seriously, why do you want to avoid a loop? Probably, you want a solution with O(1) complexity  and not a O(n) complexity solution regardless if a loop is used for not.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a loop, its simpler and likely to be faster as well.

```
List<T> list = 
while(list.size()<size) list.add(null);
```

Any other approach you use is likely to use a loop for you. If this is fine, just write your own method which hides the loop used.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want is something like this....

```
final int maxSize = 50;

List<T> v = new Vector<T>() {{setSize(maxSize);}};
```

Vectors allow you to set a size, which fills them with `null`'s.

Comment: Nice one! I would use the Vector to initialise an ArrayList, something like `List<T> v = new ArrayList<T>(new Vector<T>() {{setSize(maxSize);}});` but nice thinking.

Comment: Very interesting indeed! And as far as I can see, with an extra variable instead of double brace initialization, there is no hidden loop here: `Vector<T> tmp = new Vector<T>(maxSize);` creates an internal array of the desired size, `tmp.setSize(maxSize);` ensures that vector's `toArray()` returns an array of just that size, and  this array is used by the `ArrayList` constructor in @Paul's suggestion! (The array is unnecessarily copied once, however.)

Comment: Indeed, Vector is often overlooked by developers as being just a synchronized version of ArrayList, and dismissed for the same reason, but it does enable little gems such as this.

Answer (score 2):

new option with streams:

List resultColumn = IntStream.range(0, 10000).mapToObj(i -> null).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[100]));
for(String string : list){
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Well, you can write a hierarchy:

```
class Base<T>{
    protected List<T> list; 

    public List<T> getList(){
       return list;
    }
}

class Child extends Base<String>{
    public Child(){
        list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[100]));
    }
}
```

It can be used in the next way:

```
Base<String> base = new Child();
base.getList();
```

Comment: But I do not want a `List<String>`, I want a `List<T>` where nothing is known about `T` (at least nothing relevant to list creation).

Comment: This post does not answers the question. Obviously it is possible with concrete type, but @arme.b wants to write code for *generic* type.

Comment: What does your update change? You are still not creating the list at the point where it is needed, but at a point where the concrete type is known (which is not my class or any subclass thereof).

Comment: I don't implore you to accept my answer. This way can be used in some cases and it uses the abstraction, not the specific type.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was

```
MyClass[] array = {new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new ProfileSectionDTO(), new MyClass()};
List<MyClass> MyClassList = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Dirty, but working :)

Answer (score -2):

if you want an `ArrayList` you can use reflection to cheat

```
ArrayList<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>(numEls);
Field f = ArrayList.class.getField("size");//cache this
f.setAccessible(true);
f.setInt(myList, numEls);
```

Comment: A solution without Class object parameter or unnecessary array copies! Thank you. Nitpick: `getField(String)` is only for public fields, `getDeclaredField` is needed.

Comment: This seems dangerous; since it doesn't update the (presumed) backing-array at all it seems like an AIOOBE could be thrown later - e.g. what happens after an `add` when the internal capacity is still sufficient? It is **not** a gonna-bite-me-sometime bug I want to deal with.

Comment: @pst note I used the capacity constructor so it will match, but indeed it's a niche application

Comment: Meddling with the internals of a foreign class is wrong on so many levels. There are few exceptional situations where this is defensible. Avoiding a loop is clearly not one of them.