# Adding a element of Generic type <T> to an arrayList of LinkedList's

Tags: java, list, hashtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to make a hash table class in java where I store the key,value pairs in an ArrayList of Linked List's. I do this by declaring

```
 ArrayList<LinkedList<T>> storage = new ArrayList();
```

I then want to create a linkList object that I can use to then create a new linked list inside of each index of the arrayList. I do this by declaring:

```
  LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
```

Then I have my add function set up to add elements to the first index of the LinkedList that is inside the Hashed key index of the arrayList as such:

```
public void add(K key, T value){    
int arrayListIndex = (key.hashCode()) % this.initialCapacity;
    System.out.println(arrayListIndex); //This tells us where we access the Array List;


    if (hashBrown.get(arrayListIndex) == null){

        hashBrown.add(arrayListIndex, list);
        hashBrown.get(arrayListIndex).addFirst(value);
    }
}
```

Everytime I run this code I receive an error where my index is 7 and my size is 0. This causes an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
    at FastHashtable.add(FastHashtable.java:72)
    at FastHashtable.main(FastHashtable.java:145)
```

I am unable to track down where this index out of bounds error is coming from can anyone offer advice. I am fairly new at working with ArrayLists which makes me think my original declaration of the arrayList is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing an `ArrayList`s *capacity* with its *size*. From the Oracle Java documentation:

> Each `ArrayList` instance has a *capacity*. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an `ArrayList`, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.

Instead, you should be looking at creating a plain array (e.g. `Object[] a = new Object[maxSize]`) in which you can actually assign objects (linked lists in this case) at arbitrary index values. If you only want to store linked lists, create a `LinkedList<T>[]` array.

Comment: Sounds like the plain Object array is the way to go

Comment: @DerekDrummond If you never want to resize the array, then in principle yes, but an array of generic objects (i.e. your linked list) is difficult to deal with (and to create in the first place).

Comment: If you're interested you could take a look at the [Java HashMap source code](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/HashMap.java.html), which uses a dynamically-resized object-array (`Entry[]`) at its heart.

Comment: in 20 minutes I completed everything using an array rather than array lists which took 3 hours of frustration.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add to a list at index 7 if there are 0 elements in it. You can only add at the end (with the `add` method without index) or at a position that is no larger than the current list's `size()`.

When the list is empty and you add something at index 7, what do you expect the list to contain at the first position then, and what at index 6? (I once created a subclass of list to fill everything up to the index with `null` when the addition index is larger than the list size, but this behaviour is not universal enough to be part of `List`'s semantics.

---

[edit in response to comment here and to praseodym's answer]

You could simply [fill the (array) list with nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223177/initializing-listt-with-given-number-of-nulls-without-loop) replace those with a linked list when the respective position is first accessed. (Be sure to use `set` and not `add`, though, which is probably what you want above as well.)
Alternatively, you could create an array of the desired size (that will be full of `null`s by default) and "wrap" it into a (non-resizable) list via `Arrays.asList`. You have to ignore an "unchecked conversion" warning then, however (not that you could avoid warnings when using an array). Also, I suggest you read "[Program to an interface, not an implementation](http://www.fatagnus.com/program-to-an-interface-not-an-implementation/)".

Comment: Sounds like more work than need be and creating all of those extra arrayList index's will ruin the efficiency

Comment: err? Which extra arrayLists? (And, out of curiosity, what makes you think you can build a faster hashtable than `HashMap`?)